# name 'driver' not defined, Selenium Webdriver python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pycharm

I'm trying to open a website using Selenium WebDriver Chrome, but haven't even gotten to that as my code keeps producing errors. I have already fixed one by doubling the '' in the directory for Chrome Driver.

I am using Pycharm. I would like to know why this is happening, and a fix for it.

The error is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

and this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
Browser = driver.Chrome(r'''C:\Users\ballc\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe''')
```

Comment: you imported `webdriver`, what should be `driver` ?

Comment: @PRMoureu is it not supposed to be webdriver? I just used driver instead, it said "no module named driver"

Comment: you are supposed to import `webdriver` but why not using it instead of `driver` ?

Comment: @PRMoureu i did import webdriver do you mean driver.Chrome?

Comment: yup! what `driver.Chrome` is supposed to be ? why don't you want to use `webdriver.Chrome` instead ?

Comment: Now that produces a new error: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Comment: what version of selenium it is ? try `import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)` to see that

Comment: @PRMoureu 3.12.0

Answer (score 1):

As you have imported `webdriver` module as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

- To invoke *Chrome* through *ChromeDriver* you need to use the same `webdriver` module.
- While passing the *path* of the *ChromeDriver* you need to mention the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* i.e. the *absolute path* within single quotes (`''`) separated through single forward slash (`\`) along with the raw (`r`) switch.
- Try to avoid names of common builtin variables e.g.*Browser* to avoid cyclic dependencies.

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\ballc\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> from selenium import webdriver

you can see the module name is `webdriver`, so you should use that name.  As the error states, `driver` is not defined (you never defined it).

so..

`Browser = driver.Chrome()`

should be:

`browser = webdriver.Chrome()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')  
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```